# How to render email

Tags: android

Is there any way to render properly (images, tables, links, colors) **html** emails in Android TextView/WebView/ect.?

Right now I'm trying to use WebView, but it does not scale properly .Below is my code:

```
            // making images smaller; images will fit text view
            holder.mUiContentWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setClickable(false);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setFocusable(false);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setLongClickable(false);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

            holder.mUiContentWeb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
            holder.mUiContentWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

[image: wrong scaling]

Answer (score 0):

try to use `holder.mUiContentWeb.loadData(text, "text/html", "UTF-8");`
 and replace `holder.mUiContentWeb.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`